# After Enqueue in Wordpress, How to show my google API map

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps

I have this code in my functions.php which shows in my page source my API Key and map_script.js.

```
function google_maps_api() { 
    wp_register_script( 'googlemap', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap',true); 
    wp_register_script( 'map-script', '/js/map_script.js',true);
if( is_page( 'To the Nations Worldwide' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('googlemap');
}
if( is_page( 'To the Nations Worldwide' ) ) { 
   wp_enqueue_script('map-script'); }
} 
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'google_maps_api' );
```

This shows everything on my main page in the page source at www.tothenationsworldwide.com however the map does not show.

I have tried adding this in my CSS

```
body,html,#map-canvas{
   height:100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px
 }
```

And this on my page I want the map to display

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.tothenationsworldwide.com/js/map_script.js?ver=4.3.1'></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

No luck, I need to know what I need to do next to show my map.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with a fixed size for the map? Just for testing. Also: if I try to open your map_script.js URL I get a not found response

Comment: how do I write a fixed size for the map?  I have tested it as a html code on my computer and the code works fine.  I fixed the map_script.js from not showing, forgot the get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/map_script.js'

Comment: Try only with this: `#map-canvas{ width: 800px; height: 400px; }` (nothing for body and html) - try to look in the browser console for error logs

Comment: You're amazing. Thank you so much!